# SVN with Xcode 4 Ignore List

Tags: svn, xcode4, ignore

For Xcode 3 I always added *.mod1v3 and *.pbxuser to svn:ignore.
Which are the user-specific files in Xcode4?

My first intent would be to add the folders xcuserdata and project.xcworkcpace to svn:ignore

Under the folder `project.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/` there are some files which I don't know for what they are used within xcode.
And so I did not know if I should add them to SVN.

What are your best practices with SVN and Xcode 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:
A better English SVN-targeted on SO question and answer here:
[SVN ignore pattern with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474523/svn-ignore-pattern-with-xcode-4)

I found this blog post for GIT, which shouldn't be any different for SVN:

http://www.betawax.de/blog/2010/08/gitignore-xcode-4/

If you don't read German like me, here's Google's automatic translation:

http://translate.google.co.il/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.betawax.de%2Fblog%2F2010%2F08%2Fgitignore-xcode-4%2F

Cheers,
Oded

Answer (score 1):

Which files are you unsure of?

I've been ignoring all of `xcuserdata`. The potential loss, as I understand it, is mostly the things I also didn't put under svn in Xcode 3. And schemes I'm not sharing.

I just make sure to share any schemes I care about.

In any case, I regularly delete everything not under source control and haven't lost anything I cared about.