# SVN ignore pattern with Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, svn

(provided you use Xcode 4)
What is your SVN ignore pattern? Do you have a global one or do you prefer to set it via propset?

Comment: For some strange reason I didn't need svn ignore for Obj-C stuff so far, although I only worked on one project with another programmer on the same code. I just took a look into Xcode, and under File --> Source Control there's an 'ignore' command. Sadly, it was greyed out for me, but maybe this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have the following in my ~/.subversion/config file:

`global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store *~.nib *.mode* *.pbxuser CVS _*.java *.perspective .LSOverride *.xcuserdatad`

I added the last one (*.xcuserdatad) recently for Xcode 4.

Comment: are you sure it will work.. My ~/subversion/config file looks like 
`# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo .xcuserdatad`
`#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store ` but whenever I type ***svn status*** on command line all .xcuserdatad files are showing up

Comment: I edited the above file and changed `.xcuserdatad` to `*.xcuserdatad` . Still no luck

Comment: Krishnabhadra, something in there (like your name.xcuserdatad directory) is probably versioned. To see what, cd into your .xcworkspace package directory and do: svn -v status. You'll have to get Subversion to forget about whatever it is before it will ignore those files.

Comment: Remove the # from the beginning of the line. It denotes a comment.

Comment: I added xcuserdata (without the *. or the trailing d) to ignore all my xcuserdata folders.

Comment: removing the "#" from the beginning as TrevorL suggested worked for me !

Answer (score 4):

I added xcuserdata and *.xcworkspace to mine. Sorry, don't have wifi on my laptop or I'd paste the whole line in.