# Should I include Xcode .plist and .pch files to source control?

Tags: xcode, svn, smartsvn

Whenever creating a new project or importing an existing one, Xcode usually creates three files and a folder. The first two files are found in the root of the project:

```
ProjectNameHere-Info.plist
ProjectNameHere-Prefix.pch
```

And the folder which can also be found in the project root directoy, is called:

```
en.lproj
```

which has this file:

```
InfoPlist.strings
```

Does anyone know what the purpose of these files are/what they contain? Im not sure whether to add these to my SVN (I'm using SmartSVN). Likewise if I don't check-in these generated files, how will Xcode react  when someone else checks-out the project? Does Xcode re-create these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should include these files to source control.

'plist'  is a property list file for application written with xml 
that include icon file name, build option, and more.

'pch' is precompiled header file has referenced from all of your project.

'en.lproj' and 'InfoPlist.strings' are for language localized files.
default language have set by English.

if you remove these files, occur error on build.
and Xcode can not re create these from other files.

Comment: this question will help you using Subversion with Xcode project.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474523/svn-ignore-pattern-with-xcode-4