# SVN settings for xcode 5 (and iOS projects) - what should I ignore?

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I'm working with Cornerstone for versioning Xcode projects (among others).

I'm trying to figure out what files in my working copy should be ignored so I can work with other teammates on the same project, without loosing certificates, provisioning profiles, ...

Several developers need to be able to compile the same project for distribution.

I realize there are very similar questions out there already but I couldn't find enough justifications for the answers I've read.

I have not figured out how to manage the project.pbxproj for example. This file contains information about the project **and** the developer it seems...

Also, should I define global ignores on the SVN **client or server**??
I'm quite new to versioning so I'm sorry if my questions seem trivial.

Any help will be much appreciated. I'm looking for explanations more than pre-made answers.

Something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021580/1491212
but adapted for SVN is what I seek...

Comment: It's not the files and types you'll want to ignore that will be different, it's the way you go about ignoring them. In subversion, you have svn:ignore, within a directory, like: svn propset svn:ignore "*.jpg" . Notice the entire command, and the last two arguments: what you're ignoring, then the context, in this case . which means current directory.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got that. My problem really is about knowing which files I should rule out and how (from client or server).

Comment: ah, I see; sorry. So, using the content at the link you posted, you can issue the svn propset svn:ignore "item from that link" . command at the top level of your project and you should be good. I'm not sure as I don't use it, but xcode's built in support for version control may provide some tools for helping with this, too. hope that helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6546289/143225