# Different files which are generated after project compilation in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

On compiling my game made using Cocos2dx(c++) on Xcode 6.4, I can see various files which are generated with in DerivedData folder like :-

*.o files
*.dia files
*.d files.

I understand the first one as being object files what are the last two files ? I searched a lot but not able to find anything about them.

Edit: Checked in http://www.file-extensions.org/ also nothing there.

Comment: Nothing in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` should go in source code control. You shouldn't need to add anything to the "ignore" file. Just don't put the folder in source control.

Comment: that I am aware of that is why I am not asking if I have to ignore it or not, I just need to know what are those files

Comment: But you state "*I want to set ignore pattern for SVN"* in your question. So my comment is to let you know that you don't need that since you shouldn't put anything from the folder in source control. It's fine if you simply want to know what the files mean or represent but you should update your question if you don't care about setting up the SVN ignore file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN ignore pattern with Xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474523/svn-ignore-pattern-with-xcode-4)

Comment: No its not a duplicate, I have edited my question so that its more clear. The  link you have provided does not tell anything about *.dia and *.d files.

Comment: Look at one of the .d files. It's a text file for dependencies.

Comment: The best I've seen so far indicates that the .dia file is some sort of diagnostic file. It's a binary file.

Comment: yes I just simply dumped the *.d file and all I saw is a number of .h files, with a nice title inside file as "Dependencies" and may be *.dia is a (dia)GNOSTIC file. Thanks for help I appreciate it.